# string formatting issue within an iterative loop

Tags: python, list, iteration, string-formatting

I am trying to reformat some data and save it to an output file in python. I .strip() each line from the original and append it to a list.  I create a second list with the values I need to add to the original data, (modifications enclose original data) and iterate over it to write the modified data to the output file using string formatting operators when I need to pass in a value from the list of original data.  The output needs to insert some information presented only once into each record of the output so its not a 1:1 output (original lines to output lines) and this is where I run into my issue I believe.  Here is an example of my code...

Original data:

```
Client
#ofrecords(as an integer)
Line1ofrecord1
Line2ofrecord1
....
Line1ofrecord2
Line2ofrecord2
....
End
```

Code:

```
def shouldbesimple(originalfile):
    inputfile = open(originalfile, "r")
    outputfile = open('finaloutput.txt', "w")
    nowhitespace = originalfile.strip()
    Client = nowhitespace.pop(0)
    Counter = nowhitespace.pop(0)  (each record has exactly the same number of lines)

    #at this point only record information remains in list..

    Header = "stuff at beginning of each record in output"
    Insertclient = "NEEDED {1} CHANGES"
    Line1 = "THINGS I {0} MUST ADD"
    Footer = "stuff at end of each record in output"
    thingstoadd = [Header, Line1, Insertclient, Footer]
    while counter > 0 :
        writetofile = ""
        for element in thingstoadd:
            writetofile = element.format(nowhitespace.pop(0), Client)
            outputfile.write(writetofile + "\n")
        counter = counter - 1
    inputfile.close()
    outputfile.close()
```

Everything works as intended until I begin to iterate over thingstoadd..

The data does not line up as intended and I get a "pop from empty list" error.  Printing writetofile shows me that python is running the `nowhitespace.pop(0)` operation in the format statement on every iteration, not just when the `{0}` appears in the element in question.

Is there a more appropriate way to pass the original information into the string data, or to prevent the `.pop()` operation from occuring on every element?

Comment: please put your code in a code block (indent four spaces).  i can't read this code at all as it is.

Comment: Thank you for the ninja edit.  I was shocked when I tried to submit my own.  This is my first post so I apologize in advance for my lack of proper etiquette.  I will try to answer any questions as soon as possible while I can.

Comment: What are you intending the `nowhitespace = originalfile.strip()` call to do?  It looks to me like `originalfile` is your filename; it's odd to be calling `strip` on it and even odder to be trying to `pop` things off it later.

Comment: First, please give us the actual exception, with traceback, instead of trying to describe the error and when it happens.

Comment: I wanted to avoid any issues which might arise if the original file had an extra space at the beginning or end of the data for each line. The output has spacing built into the string I am "wrapping" around each line from originalfile.

Comment: Second, can you give us a complete (but hopefully stripped-down) input file that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @ChristopherKakert: Peter's point is that you're stripping the _filename_, not the _file contents_. And then you're iterating the filename as well, which is just going to get you the characters of that string one by one.

Comment: .pop(0) was the first thing that came to my mind to accomplish inserting, line by line, nowhitespace, into my string formatting.  Each record has, say, 5 lines of data.  I need to add string characters to the beginning and end of each line in the output file with the relevent line from nowhitespace neatly dropped inside.

Comment: @ChristopherKakert: I didn't even notice you were using `pop(0)`. There is absolutely no reason to do that to iterate a list; `while True: value = lst.pop(0)` has the same effect as `for value in lst:` except much slower and more complicated. But, more importantly, that means the code you've showed us _can't be your actual code_, because it will get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'` the time you call `pop(0)` on `nowhitespace`. We can't help you debug code which is just kind of similar to your real code, we need real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to debug your code, let me show you how I'd do what I think you want to do.

```
import itertools

# from itertools recipes in the docs
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def shouldbesimple(originalfile):
    with open(originalfile) as inputfile, open('finaloutput.txt', "w") as outputfile:
        client = next(inputfile).rstrip()
        count = int(next(inputfile).rstrip())
        groups = grouper(inputfile, 4)

        Header = "stuff at beginning of each record in output"
        Insertclient = "NEEDED {1} CHANGES"
        Line1 = "THINGS I {0} MUST ADD"
        Footer = "stuff at end of each record in output"
        thingstoadd = [Header, Line1, Insertclient, Footer]

        for _ in range(count):
            for fmt, line in zip(thingstoadd, next(groups)):
                outputfile.write(fmt.format(line.rstrip(), Client) + '\n')
```

With this input:

```
Client
2
Line1ofrecord1
Line2ofrecord1
Line3ofrecord1
Line4ofrecord1
Line1ofrecord2
Line2ofrecord2
Line3ofrecord2
Line4ofrecord2
End
```

I get this output:

```
THINGS I Line2ofrecord1 MUST ADD
NEEDED Client CHANGES
stuff at end of each record in output
stuff at beginning of each record in output
THINGS I Line2ofrecord2 MUST ADD
NEEDED Client CHANGES
stuff at end of each record in output
```

Comment: That does work, in fact, thank you!  I was just surprised that python checks the value of each statement in the .format(statement) list regardless if it is being called or not.